# How to compare 2 datasets based on one column?

Tags: r

My 2 test datasets

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = c(1, 2, 3), 
                      var2 = c("apple", "peach", "orange"), 
                      var3 = c("red","blue","green"),
                      var4 = c("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31", "2021-07-31")
                      ), 
                 row.names = c(NA,-3L), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df2 <- structure(list(var1 = c(1, 2, 3), 
                      var2 = c("apple", "peach", "orange"), 
                      var3 = c("red","purple","green"),
                      var4 = c("2021-01-01", "2021-12-24", "2021-07-31")
                      ), 
                 row.names = c(NA,-3L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Im looking to compare both tables based on `var4` so the resulting table will contain the records which have a different `var4` and are stored in `df1`. For this example above, `record 2` has a different content in `var4` so I would require to store this entire record from `df1` on `df_diff` .

```
df_diff <- structure(list(var1 = c(2), 
                      var2 = c("peach"), 
                      var3 = c("blue"),
                      var4 = c("2021-12-31")
                      ), 
                 row.names = c(NA,-1L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: So this? `df1[!df2$var4 %in% df1$var4,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### dplyr

You can use `dplyr::anti_join`.

```
anti_join(df1, df2, by="var4")
# A tibble: 1 x 4
   var1 var2  var3  var4      
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1     2 peach blue  2021-12-24
```

#### base R

```
df1[!df2$var4 %in% df1$var4,]
```

#### data.table

```
setDT(df1)[!df2, on = "var4"]
```

Comment: `anti_join` worked perfectly. somehow i forgot about this